# Laravel Package Creation

Tags: php, laravel, package

So I'm writing a Laravel Package that will eventually exist on git (or wherever).

I've created the package structure as outlined here (https://rathes.de/blog/en/laravel-package, great resource by the way), in /app/ and I've also created a Facade.php, PackageServiceProvoder.php and a controller that dumps "Hello world" to the browser.

I also have a pre-existing HomeController.php and I've added the following to the test function:

```
dd(\MyPackage::test());// <-- Should dump "Hello world" and die.
```

I've also added the following to the packages' composer.json file and run composer install:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Company\\LaravelPackageMyPackage\\": "src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Company\\LaravelPackageMyPackage\\Test\\": "tests"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
"Company\\LaravelPackageMyPackage\\Lar...kageServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "MyPackage": "Company\\LaravelPackageMyPackage\\Facade"
        }
    }
},
```

The problem I have is that when I run this in the browser I get the following error:

```
Class 'MyPackage' not found // <-- references the dd() line of code above
```

I must have missed a step during the tutorial or something like that because as far as I can see it should be working now.
Any suggestions guys?

Laravel 5.5, PHP 7.1, Ubuntu Linux os.

Just code below here:

```
File structure (very similar to this):
Project -> app -> my-package /

├── database/
│   ├── .gitkeep
├── config/
│   ├── package-name.php
├── src/
│   ├── PackageNameServiceProvider.php
├── tests/
│   ├── TestCase.php
├── .gitignore
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── composer.json
├── LICENSE
├── phpunit.xml
├── README.md

// FACADE:
<?php
namespace Company\LaravelPackageMyPackage;

class Facade extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'laravelpackagemypackage';
    }
}

// MY PACKAGE
<?php
namespace Company\LaravelPackageMyPackage;

class LaravelPackageMyPackage
{
    public function test()
    {
        return "Hello From My Package!";
    }
}

// SERVICE PROVIDER:
<?php
namespace Company\LaravelPackageMyPackage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LaravelPackageMyPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {
        //$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations/');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('laravelpackagemypackage', function () {
            return new LaravelPackageMyPackage();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you make composer aware that you have a composer package living in `app` that needs to be managed by composer? where did you run `composer install` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Make sure that your class namespace is the same as the composer.json
In your ServiceProvider and Facade the namespace should be

```
 namespace Company\LaravelPackageMyPackage
```

Also check that your Facade is returning the right string

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'mypackage';
}
```

In your ServiceProvider register method

```
App::bind('mypackage', function () {
    return new MyPackage();
});
```

EDIT

You have written laravelpackageMyPackage but it should be laravelpackagemypackage in your getFacadeAccessor()

Edit
When calling MyPackage::test() try adding

```
use MyPackage;
```

in your controller if that does not work

try calling the facade directly

Company\LaravelPackageMyPackage\Facade::test()

Comment: Thanks very much for the hint! Namespace: "Company\LaravelPackageMyPackage" is the same in all 3 files and the composer.json. I also have this "laravelpackagemypackage" as the facade string and it's the same in both places but still Class 'MyPackage' not found :-(

Comment: @Donal.Lynch.Msc Okay. Btw should it be \MyPackage::test(). Is it not supposed to be MyPackage::test(). Also could you share your serviceprovider and MyPackage and your file structure?

Comment: When I change it from \MyPackage::test(). to MyPackage::test() the error then changes to: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MyPackage' not found". Also, updated question.

Comment: @Donal.Lynch.Msc looks like you have a mismatch in the bind and get a getFacadeAccessor

Comment: That's just a copy & paste error from uploading the code. Fixed question.